# What happened to OpenRT?

Tags: real-time, raytracing

I have been looking around for powerful raytracing interfaces and discovered references to OpenRT but can't seem to find it anywhere. Does it even still exist?

If it is gone, what is the most used library for raytracing that is powerful enough for realtime rendering.

My answer below is all I have managed to find.

### Update

I have continued my search and only seem to find OpenRL as it supports most of what I need. However I may end up writing my own wrapper or engine that suits my needs as there seems to be no mature solution. Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: An API that is likely to meet your needs and is much more mature is OptiX from Nvidia.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PowerVR Wizard GPUs by Imagination Technologies have been announced recently.

> "Wizard is essentially an extension of Imagination’s existing PowerVR
>   Series6XT Rogue designs, taking the base hardware and adding the
>   additional blocks necessary to do ray tracing"

Answer (score 0):

Possible, and seems to be the only, solution I have found is [OpenRL](https://caustic.com/openrlsdk.php).